# List all indexeddb for one host in firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, indexeddb

I figured if the devtool [can list](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/server/actors/storage.js#1921) all created IndexedDB, then there should be an API to retrieve them...?

Dose anyone know how I get get a list of names with the help of a firefox SDK?

Comment: I think you'll have to do it the same devtools does it. They might not have an api but they should have some functions in there with comments that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I did dig into the code and looked at the source. unfortunately there wasn't any convenient API that would pull out all the databases from one host.

The way they did it was to lurk around in the user profiles folder and look at all folder and files for .sqlite and make a sql query (multiple times in case there is an ongoing transaction) to each .sqlite and ask for the database name

it came down this peace of code

```
// striped down version of: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/server/actors/storage.js

/* This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
 * License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
 * file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. */

"use strict";

const {async} = require("resource://gre/modules/devtools/async-utils");
const { setTimeout } = require("sdk/timers");
const promise = require("sdk/core/promise");

// A RegExp for characters that cannot appear in a file/directory name. This is
// used to sanitize the host name for indexed db to lookup whether the file is
// present in <profileDir>/storage/default/ location
const illegalFileNameCharacters = [
  "[",
  // Control characters \001 to \036
  "\\x00-\\x24",
  // Special characters
  "/:*?\\\"<>|\\\\",
  "]"
].join("");
const ILLEGAL_CHAR_REGEX = new RegExp(illegalFileNameCharacters, "g");

var OS = require("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm").OS;
var Sqlite = require("resource://gre/modules/Sqlite.jsm");

/**
 * An async method equivalent to setTimeout but using Promises
 *
 * @param {number} time
 *        The wait time in milliseconds.
 */
function sleep(time) {
  let deferred = promise.defer();

  setTimeout(() => {
    deferred.resolve(null);
  }, time);

  return deferred.promise;
}

var indexedDBHelpers = {

  /**
   * Fetches all the databases and their metadata for the given `host`.
   */
  getDBNamesForHost: async(function*(host) {
    let sanitizedHost = indexedDBHelpers.getSanitizedHost(host);
    let directory = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.profileDir, "storage",
                                 "default", sanitizedHost, "idb");

    let exists = yield OS.File.exists(directory);
    if (!exists && host.startsWith("about:")) {
      // try for moz-safe-about directory
      sanitizedHost = indexedDBHelpers.getSanitizedHost("moz-safe-" + host);
      directory = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.profileDir, "storage",
                               "permanent", sanitizedHost, "idb");
      exists = yield OS.File.exists(directory);
    }
    if (!exists) {
      return [];
    }

    let names = [];
    let dirIterator = new OS.File.DirectoryIterator(directory);
    try {
      yield dirIterator.forEach(file => {
        // Skip directories.
        if (file.isDir) {
          return null;
        }

        // Skip any non-sqlite files.
        if (!file.name.endsWith(".sqlite")) {
          return null;
        }

        return indexedDBHelpers.getNameFromDatabaseFile(file.path).then(name => {
          if (name) {
            names.push(name);
          }
          return null;
        });
      });
    } finally {
      dirIterator.close();
    }
    return names;
  }),

  /**
   * Removes any illegal characters from the host name to make it a valid file
   * name.
   */
  getSanitizedHost: function(host) {
    return host.replace(ILLEGAL_CHAR_REGEX, "+");
  },

  /**
   * Retrieves the proper indexed db database name from the provided .sqlite
   * file location.
   */
  getNameFromDatabaseFile: async(function*(path) {
    let connection = null;
    let retryCount = 0;

    // Content pages might be having an open transaction for the same indexed db
    // which this sqlite file belongs to. In that case, sqlite.openConnection
    // will throw. Thus we retey for some time to see if lock is removed.
    while (!connection && retryCount++ < 25) {
      try {
        connection = yield Sqlite.openConnection({ path: path });
      } catch (ex) {
        // Continuously retrying is overkill. Waiting for 100ms before next try
        yield sleep(100);
      }
    }

    if (!connection) {
      return null;
    }

    let rows = yield connection.execute("SELECT name FROM database");
    if (rows.length != 1) {
      return null;
    }

    let name = rows[0].getResultByName("name");

    yield connection.close();

    return name;
  })

};

module.exports = indexedDBHelpers.getDBNamesForHost;
```

If anyone want to use this then here is how you would use it

```
var getDBNamesForHost = require("./getDBNamesForHost");

getDBNamesForHost("http://example.com").then(names => {
  console.log(names);
});
```

Think it would be cool if someone were to build a addon that adds `indexedDB.mozGetDatabaseNames` to work the same way as `indexedDB.webkitGetDatabaseNames`. I'm not doing that... will leave it up to you if you want. would be a grate dev tool to have ;)